# Use Json Object as Spring MVC view model directly without converting it to Java object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jsp-tags

I am working on a spring MVC project and currently making a new API call to a backend service to get response and use it as the viewModel of Spring MVC ModelAndView.

However, unlike traditional flow, this time I dont' want to convert the json object as java POJO object first. Instead, I want to use the json object as the viewModel of the ModelAndView directly. Meanwhile, I also want to access the json object naturally in jsp as if I am accessing the java POJO object.  Is this possible?

```
@RequestMapping(value = {SOME_VALUE})
public ModelAndView myFunction() {
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("myViewName");
  //getAPIResponseASJsonObject() return json object, with frameworks, I can convert it to Gson JsonObject, or org.json JSONObject
  modelAndView.addObject("viewModel", getAPIResponseASJsonObject());
  
...
  return modelAndView

}
```

I know in jsp I can access json object with EL. But I need use some "escape" mechanism if I want to combine it with standard JSTL taglib.

```
// if I have a Json object "Person" as viewModel like below in jsp:

{
  "name": "john",
  "age": 30
}


// then in jsp file if I want to access the name property, I need to write jsp like this:

${Person.get("name")}

//or
<c:set var="name" value="${Person.get(\"name\")}">
```

This looks unnatural compared with using Java POJO viewModel. And the jsp may be hard to maintain if the json object is complicated.

With Java POJO, I can easily write

```
//Person POJO
public Class Person{
 private String name;
 private int age;

//getter and setter

}


<c:set var="name" value="${Person.name}">
```

to access the name attribute.

Possible solutions I think maybe:

1. Assuming I am using Google Gson, I can try to create JsonObjectBean, JsonArrayBean, JsonPrimitiveBean which extend JsonElement abstract class so that I "magically" convert the json object java class to java bean.
2. Write dedicated JSP tags to avoid using escape.

Comment: I think you're saying that you're receiving from some backend API call a JSON response, correct? And what's the reason you don't want to convert that to a POJO?

Comment: Yes, I am receiving JSON response from the backend API call. 

The reason is the new API call is a platform-level API, it returns different JSON responses based on different requests.  I also want to make the controller which calls the new API "global", so that I don't need to create dedicated POJOs for different responses

Comment: In that case, I don't think you're going to find anything better than what you have. I think `${Person.get("name")}` is about as simple as you can get without a POJO